# mysql query to retrieve columns which have more than n rows

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql schema such as

```
table 1

id  field
1   field 1
2   field 2
3   field 3
```

table 2

```
id tbl1id somefield
1  1      field1
2  1      field1
3  2      field1
4  2      field1
5  1      field1
6  2      field1
7  2      field1
8  3      field1
9  1      field1
```

I am trying to write a query to get the "tbl1id" from table 2 which have more than "3" rows in this case it is 1 and 2 which have more than 3 rows in table 2.

Comment: How is `table 1` related to your question?

Answer (score 8):

```
SELECT tblid
FROM `table2`
GROUP BY tblid
HAVING COUNT(id)>3
```

This will o/p as:

tblid
 1
 2

Comment: `count(id)>2` ? he is looking for more than 3 rows